# xdotool refresh Browser with php or shell

Tags: php, browser, sh, refresh, xdotool

have a RPI in Kioskmode running.

I wrote a php script that display a Scoreboard for Tabletennis, the points count up when press pushbuttons which are connected to a D1 Mini which is connected over wlan.

Now i need to refresh the Browserwindow to display the actual score from the database.

i found **xdotool** but i cant get it to work with shell_exec() in the php script.

When i use this command `DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool key F5` in commandline the browser refresh work, but when i try to du this out of a php script i cant get it to work.

Can someone help me get this running?

I tryed various versions:

1. `$cmd = shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/refresh-browser.sh");`
2. `$cmd = shell_exec("sudo pi 'DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool key F5'");`

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** run `xhost si:localuser:www-data`

The issue is that the browser runs the php script with the user `www-data`, which is not authorized to access the X window system.
To see what user is running the script, add `echo shell_exec("whoami");` to your script.

You can also run the script from command line as `www-data` user, to see any errors that might not show in your browser, like this: `sudo -u www-data php your_script_filename.php`
You can run `xhost` to see the access control status and authorized users, `xhost +` to disable it (not recommended, it completely deactivates authentication and allows everyone to access all applications on your screen), `xhost -` to (re)enable access control

**SOLUTION:**
Add the `www-data` user to the authorized access list for the X server with:

```
xhost si:localuser:www-data
```

Testing:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ export DISPLAY=:0
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:pi
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ sudo -u www-data xdotool  getactivewindow
No protocol specified
Error: Can\'t open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ xhost si:localuser:www-data
localuser:www-data being added to access control list
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:www-data
SI:localuser:pi
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ sudo -u www-data xdotool  getactivewindow
20971521
```

Comment: Hi, i didnt get a message that i got a response to this one :)